# Integral of $\frac{1}{\sqrt x(1+16x^2)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to find the integral of $\frac{1}{\sqrt x(1+16x^2)}$
With the substitution $u=4\sqrt x$ I get $\int\frac{du}{2(1+u^4)}$ which is quite complicated to integrate. Is there an easier way to do this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the integral looks like it will be quite ugly. I would continue with your $u$ sub and make use of the fact that $1+16u^4 = 16(u^2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}u + \frac{1}{4})(u^2 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}u + \frac{1}{4})$ along with partial fractions decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
$$\int {\frac{1}{x^4+1}dx}=\int {\frac{1}{x^4+2x^2+1-2x^2}dx}=\int {\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2-(\sqrt2 x)^2)}dx}$$
Then do partitioning and...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\begin{align} \int\dfrac{\mathrm du}{2(1+u^4)} &=\int\dfrac{\frac1{u^2}}{2\left(\frac1{u^2}+u^2\right)}\mathrm du\\ &=\int\dfrac{\frac2{u^2}}{4\left(\frac1{u^2}+u^2\right)}\mathrm du\\ &=\int\dfrac{1+\frac1{u^2}-1+\frac1{u^2}}{4\left(\frac1{u^2}+u^2\right)}\mathrm du\\
&=\frac14 (I_1-I_2)
\end{align}$$
,where  $$I_1= \int\dfrac{1+\frac1{u^2}}{\left(\frac1{u^2}+u^2\right)}\mathrm du$$ and $$I_2= \int\dfrac{1-\frac1{u^2}}{\left(\frac1{u^2}+u^2\right)}\mathrm du.$$
Now for  $I_1$, take $t=u-\dfrac1u$ and for $I_2$, take $v=u+\dfrac1u$.

**PS**: I think this is a well-known method for solving $\int\tfrac{\mathrm du}{1+u^4}$. If it is not, all credit goes to my high-school maths teacher.